# How to fix this "your system administrator has configured chrome to open an alternate browser to access"

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying open an application in google chrome, when I launch the website chrome it redirects to IE and showing message "your system administrator has configured chrome to open an alternate browser to access" in chrome. How to overcome this issue

Answer (score 1):

**Behavior**

- You open a corporate site. For example,
  http://legacy_SharePoint_2010.com
- You will see a message: "Your
  system administrator has configured chrome to open an alternate
  browser to access"
- Your IE 11 will be opened and your chrome tab will be closed:

[image]

**Why this is happening**

- The behavior is controlled by the Chrome Policies (chrome://policy/)

[image]

- When Policy is setup, chrome://browser-switch protocol is used to redirect to IE
- The list of sites that will be forced to use IE 11 is listed in the  registry, under Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\BrowserSwitcherUrlList

[image]

- You might need local admin permissions to modify or remove these registry keys 
  :

Answer (score 0):

When your company forces such policy by default than sooner or later you have to update the policy in regedit again. Quite elegant solution could be to switch off/on the policy when needed. I do so with Python and winreg module (but could be similar in other languages):

```
import winreg
from itertools import count

def switch_reg_browser_switcher():
    reg_handler = winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
    with winreg.OpenKey(reg_handler, r"SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome", 0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS) as regkey:
        for i in count():
            try:
                val_name, curr_value, _ = winreg.EnumValue(regkey,i)
                if val_name == 'BrowserSwitcherEnabled':     
                    print(val_name, curr_value)
                    winreg.SetValueEx(regkey, val_name, 0, winreg.REG_DWORD, curr_value^1)
                    break
            except OSError:
                print('All keys iterated but "BrowserSwitcherEnabled" not found')
                break

print('Updating Windows registry to reset company policy...')
switch_reg_browser_switcher()
```

Or a simple solution in Batch file:

```
@echo off
set regkey="HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome" 
REG QUERY %regkey% /v BrowserSwitcherEnabled
if %errorlevel% equ 0 ( REG ADD %regkey% /v BrowserSwitcherEnabled /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
) else (echo no such value)
```

My motivation to do this was webscraping with Selenium (Chrome driver is much faster than IE) and no power to force my company to change policy.