# Why do my local debug websites always open in Internet Explorer?

Tags: asp.net, angular, testing, internet-explorer, windows-10

I have two entirely separate web apps that display the same behavior on Windows 10. One is an Angular 8/nodejs 16 app that I can serve locally with `ng serve`. The 2nd is an older ASP.NET site that I build/run locally via Visual Studio. The behavior is this:

If I try to access the local website via localhost in Chrome or Edge, the site is immediately opened instead in Internet Explorer. Attempting to open in Firefox, however, *is* successful.

I recently upgraded computers and am only experiencing this on the new machine. I have been unable to identify what could be causing this. Windows default browser is set to Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...it's an IT policy that has the respective browsers always open specific URLs in IE--in this case, localhost. I was able identify this by videoing the screen and noticing a message that popped up for only a few milliseconds:

```
Your system administrator has configured Google Chrome to open Internet Explorer to access localhost.
```

With that error, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54739787/how-to-fix-this-your-system-administrator-has-configured-chrome-to-open-an-alte) question on SO with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your computer, change your default web browser as:
settings-->default apps-->web browser